# jQuery separate function for each clone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem of making each clone to be independent, currently if I click on any clone, the whole "army" will perform the function (slideToggle() ), not just the single div that I want.

So here is my jQuery script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").click(function(){
        $(".resource").slideToggle();
        });
    $('#clone').click(function(){
        $('div:first').clone().appendTo('body');
    });
});
```

And my body

```
<body>
<button id="clone">Add item</button>
<div class="my_inventory">
    <div class="box"> 
    <h2>CLICK HERE</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="resource"> 
    <p>CONTENT HERE</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

To recap, I want each of the "box" of a clone to be open and close on its own by clicking on the respective `<h2>`

My guess is that I need to address `this` somewhere instead of just the class in the jQuery, but I have been trying `$(this).find('.resource')` without any success.

Comment: There's something missing in your code. Where does the element with the id "clone" get created?

Comment: apart from no `id="clone"` you really haven't explained exactly what the problem is either

Comment: I'm sorry, just edited to make it clearer

Comment: You want to click the `h2` to toggle the `.box` or the `.resource`?

Comment: toggle the `.resource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the elements (except for the first) aren't in the DOM when you bind the event-handler, you need to delegate the event-handling to an ancestor that *is* in the DOM, in this case the closest ancestor that exists is the `body` element, therefore:

```
// selecting the closest ancestor element to the dynamically-added elements
// that is present in the DOM at the point of event-binding:
$('body')
// using on() to listen for the event(s) (in this case 'click') that occurs on
// the '.box' element(s),
// and then executes the anonymous function:
.on('click', '.box', function () {
    // looks to the parent of the clicked-element:
    $(this).parent()
    // finds the '.resource' element(s):
    .find('.resource')
    // applies the slideToggle() method:
    .slideToggle();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fWE2u/).

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).